How do I "Tap Mama"?
The unlock condition for the hidden story "Gunman's Excerpt No. 05" says to "Tap Mama 50 times". I've tried tapping on Mama in my menu, but nothing happened. Clicking the "Try" button doesn't seem to do anything either.
How do I tap Mama?


Mama is the white ghost that follows you around. You have to tap on her during gameplay.
Use the Map to warp to a Chapter with Mama, (for example, chapter 1), then tap on Mama 50 times.

